# I deleted usr/bin/ruby how can I fix this?

Tags: macos

I won't go into the details of why I did this because I already feel stupid enough but I deleted ruby from the use/bin folder and now Brew does not want to work.

How can I fix this?

(I am on Lion)

Comment: Try reinstalling Xcode and developer's tools.

Comment: Can't you restore this file from a Time Machine backup?

Comment: no time machine here (yes, I know...). Tried to reinstall Xcode but it did not add it back

Comment: This isn't answer but you can replace the remove command with an alias to just move the file to a folder to store your files before you decide to permanently delete the files. It's like to have a trash desktop icon but on the command line. You can either replace rm or create a new command for example del. If you replace rm command and you want to delete a file just move the file to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby isn't a critical system file (as far as I know), so I'd imagine you should be able to reinstall it. Just follow the same procedure you did to install Ruby in the first place. See e.g. [official instructions](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/).

Comment: That doesn't really work on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

On a standard system, `/usr/bin/ruby` is a symlink to `../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby`

If you still have that file, you can just link it back:

```
sudo ln -s '../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby' /usr/bin/ruby
```